# How do I create a menu entry for Intellij in Linux Mint?

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, linux-mint, cinnamon

I've installed using snap command on terminal and nothing appears on my Cinnamon menu. I tried nothing, beacuse I'm new in this world.

Comment: maybe this will help https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206855565-Creating-desktop-menu-items-for-Intellij-IDEA-in-Linux

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for https://unix.stackexchange.com/ because while it mentions programming tools it appears to be more about [Cinnamon menu](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon-menus).

Answer (score 29):

Not sure if this will work just the same for your OS (I use Ubuntu 16.04), but in Intellij you can go to Tools -> Create Desktop Entry. I believe that will give you an entry in your search menu.

[image]

Comment: I can't find this option under the Tools menu.

Comment: I added a screenshot of what it looks like on intellij 2016.3. What version do you have, and does yours looks like this. Maybe a screenshot of what you are seeing would be useful.

Comment: Still works with PyCharm 2020.3 Community Edition under Linux Mint Cinnamon. Thanks for the tip!.

Comment: If you cannot find "Create Desktop Entry" in the Tools menu, use Find Action... (Ctrl+Shift+A)